# getaddrinfo and IPv6

Tags: c, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to understand what the getaddrinfo function returns :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{


struct addrinfo *res = 0 ;

  getaddrinfo("localhost", NULL ,NULL,&res);
  printf("ai_flags -> %i\n", res->ai_flags) ;
  printf("ai_family -> %i\n", res->ai_family) ;
  printf("ai_socktype -> %i\n", res->ai_socktype) ;
  printf("ai_protocol -> %i\n", res->ai_protocol) ;
  printf("ai_addrlen -> %i\n", res->ai_addrlen) ;
  struct sockaddr_in* saddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;
  printf("ai_addr hostname ->  %s\n", inet_ntoa(saddr->sin_addr));

  freeaddrinfo(res);

  return 0 ;
}
```

results :

```
ai_flags -> 40
ai_family -> 2
ai_socktype -> 1
ai_protocol -> 6
ai_addrlen -> 16
ai_addr hostname ->  127.0.0.1
```

In /etc/hosts, I 've got :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost    
::1     localhost
```

Getaddrinfo returns only 127.0.0.1 and not ::1 ? I don't understand why ?

The second question is where can I find the meaning of those ints (40,2,1,6 etc) ? I've read the man but there is nothing about that.

I also wanted to know if it's possible to give a IPv6 adress (for example ::1) and the function returns the name : localhost ?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: According to the manual page, getaddrinfo allocates space and fills a linked list beginning at &res. I think it would return more than one entry, and you need to iterate through the linked list by res->ainext

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@jwodder and @onteria_ covered the IPv6 portion well, so I'll just tackle the *numbers* portion:

```
ai_flags -> 40
```

Probably this is going to be the sum of the following two in `/usr/include/netdb.h`:

```
# define AI_V4MAPPED    0x0008  /* IPv4 mapped addresses are acceptable.  */
# define AI_ADDRCONFIG  0x0020  /* Use configuration of this host to choose
```

This is the *protocol family*, inet, inet6, apx, unix, etc.:

```
ai_family -> 2

bits/socket.h:78:#define    PF_INET     2   /* IP protocol family.  */
bits/socket.h:119:#define   AF_INET     PF_INET
```

This is the *socket type*, stream, dgram, packet, rdm, seqpacket:

```
ai_socktype -> 1

bits/socket.h:42:  SOCK_STREAM = 1,     /* Sequenced, reliable, connection-based
```

The higher-level *protocol*, TCP, UDP, TCP6, UDP6, UDPlite, ospf, icmp, etc:

```
ai_protocol -> 6
```

Funny enough, in `/etc/protocols`:

```
tcp 6   TCP     # transmission control protocol
```

The size of the `struct sockaddr`. (Differs based on the address family! Ugh.)

```
ai_addrlen -> 16
```

This is because you're getting back a `struct sockaddr_in`, see `linux/in.h`:

```
#define __SOCK_SIZE__   16      /* sizeof(struct sockaddr)  */
struct sockaddr_in {
  sa_family_t       sin_family; /* Address family       */
  __be16        sin_port;   /* Port number          */
  struct in_addr    sin_addr;   /* Internet address     */

  /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'. */
  unsigned char     __pad[__SOCK_SIZE__ - sizeof(short int) -
            sizeof(unsigned short int) - sizeof(struct in_addr)];
};
```

And the last one, from `/etc/hosts` :)

```
ai_addr hostname ->  127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 10):

`res` also contains a field `struct addrinfo *ai_next;`, which is a pointer to additional entries found by `getaddrinfo`, or NULL if there were no other entries.  If you examine `res->ai_next`, you should find the IPv6 entry.

As for the integer fields in a `struct addrinfo`, they correspond to predefined constants with implementation-defined values, and the integer values themselves are not of general interest.  If you want to know what a given field means, compare it against the constants that can be assigned to that field (`SOCK_STREAM`, `SOCK_DGRAM`, etc. for `ai_socktype`; `IPPROTO_TCP`, `IPPROTO_UDP`, etc. for `ai_protocol`; and so forth) or, for `ai_flags`, test each bit corresponding to a predefined constant (e.g., `if (res->ai_flags & AI_NUMERICHOST) {printf("ai_flags has AI_NUMERICHOST\n"); }`).

Answer (score 6):

```
extern struct sockaddr_in6 create_socket6(int port, const char * address) {

    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *resalloc;
    struct sockaddr_in6 input_socket6;
    int errcode;

    /* 0 out our structs to be on the safe side */
    memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
    memset (&input_socket6, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

    /* We only care about IPV6 results */
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_DEFAULT;

    errcode = getaddrinfo (address, NULL, &hints, &res);
    if (errcode != 0)
    {
     perror ("[ERROR] getaddrinfo ");
     return input_socket6;
    }

    resalloc = res;

    while (res)
    {
        /* Check to make sure we have a valid AF_INET6 address */
        if(res->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
                /* Use memcpy since we're going to free the res variable later */
                        memcpy (&input_socket6, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

                       /* Here we convert the port to network byte order */
                        input_socket6.sin6_port = htons (port);
                        input_socket6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
               break;
        }

        res = res->ai_next;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(resalloc);

    return input_socket6;
}
```

Here is some code that explains it. Basically unless you give getaddrinfo some hints to tell it to only work with IPV6, it will also give IPV4 results. That is why you have to loop through the results as shown.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have been given to most parts, but to answer this final part:

> I also wanted to know if it's possible to give a IPv6 adress (for example ::1) and the function returns the name : localhost ?

The function you want there is `getnameinfo()`; given a socket address it returns a string name.